# HTML 5 pattern regex to accept twitter handle like words, starting with @ only

Tags: regex, html

I'm trying to develop a HTML5 form validation technique for a form input to accept words starting with the @ character only, like twitter handles.

For example to accept: @photography101

And reject: photography101
OR @photography@101

It must accept only a string in the same.format as twitter handles. one @ character only, no spaces and the @ character must be at the beginning.

My form input is as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="pagehandle" pattern="^@\s[a-z0-9]" required="required" \>
```

But this pattern is not accepting words entered in the input area that start with @

Can anyone help with the correct regex pattern?

Comment: Your pattern 

    `"^@\s[a-z0-9]"`

currently only matches strings that start with `@`, followed by exactly one whitespace character, followed by one alphanumeric character.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
pattern="^@[a-z0-9]+$"
```

where the `+` means *one or more times*

`$` is the *end of string* anchor

the `\s` seems useless.

Comment: `^@\w+$` \w is equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9] which suits a bit more , do you agree? :)

Comment: @Holybreath: not exactly, `\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. And for regex engines that are set to deal with utf8 `\w` means all letters and number in all alphabets and underscore. But in the present case you can replace `[a-zA-Z0-9]` by `[^\W_]`